# Django url that changes with argument passed

Tags: python

I am making a shopping website and I want to make one url that will help in separating men and women's apparel.

What I want to do

when you enter `.../men/` it should display all products whose gender matches men
and same for `.../women/`

my url looks like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload, name='uploadproduct'),
    url(r'^(?P<gender>\w+)/$', views.sex),
    # url(r'^(?P<gender>\w+)', views.sex,),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but whatever alphanumeric argument I pass in gender in the url, it does not recognize it. It display **Men's Products**.
example even if I go `.../nfjwiene/` it will display all men's products.
and also if I go `.../women/` the same happens.

my view looks:

```
def sex(request, gender=''):
    if gender == 'men' or 'Men':
        u='M'
    elif gender == 'women' or 'Women':
        u='F'
    else:
        u='err'
    result = Product.objects.filter(sex=u)
    return render(request, 'sex.html', {'item': result}, gender)
```

Comment: And what is your question? What happens when you use this code?

Comment: suppose I type in my address bar .../men/ or .../women/ or .../jnveorv/ the result on the template is same in all 3 cases. i.e. in all 3 cases the query from database which matches gender men is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is in your if statement;

```
if gender == 'men' or 'Men':
```

Always returns True, it checks if gender equals 'men' first, and if it fails, goes to the second condition which is just 'Men', which resolves to True. You should write your if statement as follows:

```
if gender == 'men' or gender == 'Men':
```

Same goes for woman check as well.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you.